# dynamic proxy and method annotation

Tags: java, annotations, dynamic-proxy

I have the following classes:

```
interface Ivisitor{

    @deduceStrategy("...")
    void visit(Icosmos c);
}
```

Visitor implements this interface:

```
class Visitor implements Ivisitor{
        @deduceStrategy("...") 
    public void visit(Icosmos c) 
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

The dynamic proxy:

```
public class strategyLoader{
    public static <T> T  create(Class<T> clazz,Object wrap) {
       T object = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(strategyLoader.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { clazz },new Handler(wrap)); 
       return object;

    }
}
```

Relevant portion of the handler class:

```
public class Handler implements InvocationHandler {
 Object obj;
 public Handler(Object obj) {
 this.obj = obj;
 }

public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(deduceStrategy.class)) {
     Class[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
     if((parameterTypes.length==1)&&(**Icosmos.class.isInstance(parameterTypes[0])**))
         {
            ........
         }
```

I need to load the appropriate strategy based on the exact type of Icosmos passed into Visitor.visit.
However,the parameter[0] is never resolving to an instance of Icosmos.
Would appreciate if someone showed me the way out.
The client invokes visitor as:

```
Ivisitor visitor = strategyLoader.create(Ivisitor.class,Visitor.class.newInstance());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Icosmos.class.isInstance(parameterTypes[0])
```

is exactly equivalent to `parameterTypes[0] instanceof Icosmos`, and checks whether the object `parameterTypes[0]` is an instance of `Icosmos` (which it isn't - it's a `java.lang.Class`).

There are two possibilities for what you really need.  One would be

```
Icosmos.class.isAssignableFrom(parameterTypes[0])
```

which checks whether the class `parameterTypes[0]` is assignment-compatible with `Icosmos`, i.e. given an `x` which is an instance of the class represented by `parameterTypes[0]`, would

```
Icosmos foo = x;
```

be legal without a cast.  This would check that the *declared* type of the first formal parameter is compatible with `Icosmos`.

The second alternative would be

```
args[0] instanceof Icosmos
```

which checks the *runtime* type of the actual argument value rather than the declared type of the formal parameter.

Comment: instanceof did not compile:

inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Class
required: com.patterns.visitor.Icosmos

isassignablefrom did work. 
What causes this difference?
When would a type be assignable but not an instance of a base interface or class?

Comment: @IUnknown I'm not quite sure what you mean here - `isAssignableFrom` tests for a relationship between two `java.lang.Class` objects, the `instanceof` operator tests an object reference against a class or interface name. The dynamic version of `instanceof` to test an object reference against a `java.lang.Class` is the `isInstance()` method you started with.